# Including brackets in the preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a proper replace function

I have below code to remove all URLs in the excerpt:
`return preg_replace( '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $excerpt );`

However, URLs are appearing in brackets i.e. (https://imperium...)

So, there are left ()

How should I adapt the code to also have the brackets removed?

Thank you for help.
Regards,
Jakub

Comment: I really don’t like increasing the complexity of a given RegEx unless I really need to. I’d change the replacement from an empty string to a sigil that you expect to never find in your comments, such as `%URL%`. Then perform a second pass with that known sigil that also looks for brackets, parentheses, etc., and removes them. The sigil can be anything, I just picked something quick.

Comment: Thank you Chris. However I am not sure if I understand how exactly the code should like. Can you please drop me the line for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-pass version. I've left the original RegEx exactly as-is, and just assuming it is working for you.

Instead of removing the value by using `''`, I'm replacing it by `!!URL!!`. That string isn't necessarily special in anyway, except that I'm assuming that it will never exist in the original text. It could be anything, `%CHEESE%`, `8675309`, or even a GUID. The format doesn't even matter, but I usually but special things around it like exclamation points or percent signs just to make it even less likely to collide.

The second pass then looks for that special string, optionally surrounded by parenthesis. You can add some additional brackets tests there, too. And `preq_quote` guarantees that whatever the special string is, it will be properly escape for RegEx automatically.

```php
function removeUrl(string $string): string
{
    $sigil = '!!URL!!';
    $pass1 = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', $sigil, $string);
    $pass2 = preg_replace('/\(?'.preg_quote($sigil, '/').'\)?/', '', $pass1);

    return $pass2;
}

$data = <<<EOT
Lorem ipsum (https://example.com) lorem ipsum https://example.net
EOT;

var_dump(removeUrl($data));
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/muTGF

Comment: Thank you. Will adapt my code and let you know if it helped!